# Make items of flex stay on the left side of the column axis

Tags: html, css

I have a row of flex items. There are multiple rows with different values. When the multiple rows are displayed, the column alignment of every column is messed up.

[image]

I need the headings and the row items to be in a perfect straight line. How do I achieve thi?

Current approach:

HTML for header:

```
<div className="cex-content-heading">
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-1">Symbol</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-2">Bought Trades</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-3">Sold Trades</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-4">Bought Trade Value</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-5">Sold Trade Value</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-6">Trades %</p>
  <p className="cex-content-heading-item-7">No. of Trades</p>
</div>
```

CSS for header:

```
.cex-content-heading {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

CSS for rows:

```
.cex-trending-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**GRID APPROACH**

[image]

When I use grid, the rows items are aligned right but the header has weird left margin and does not align right with the rows below.

CSS for both:

```
  .cex-content-heading {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    }
    .cex-trending-row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    }
```

Comment: Use grid instead of flex

Comment: That gives the same alignment issue

Comment: The repeating columns are different objects printed through a map function hence all of them are one-row items. Isn't flex more efficient for such cases?

Comment: Please check edits @yainspan

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table tag which helps you arrange data into rows and columns , [check more here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and you can style table cells as follows to keep the column alignment.

```
text-align: center;
```